# Envision vs Envisage

Tags: differences, verbs, synonyms

Is there a context where *envision* is not a synonym of *envisage*, or vice versa?

[Envisage's definition:](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/envisage?q=envisage)

> contemplate or conceive of as a possibility or a desirable future event

[Envision's definiton](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/envision)

> imagine as a future possibility; visualize:

[*Visualise's* definition](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/visualize?q=visualise) seems to be relevant to *envision* only in so far as it means imagine, which seems to me to be synonymous with "contemplate or conceive of".

Comment: Their etymologies are different: [envision](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=envision) is an early 20th c coinage, [envisage](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=envisage) is borrowed from French in 18th c. But I can't see much usage difference. They feel identical.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems to be a regional distinction.   British English prefers envisage, but American English prefers envision.  There's a long explanation [here](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-env1.htm) as to the history.

British:

[image]

American:

[image]

As an American English speaker, I don't think I've ever seen envisage in general usage.

Answer (score 9):

The definition and usage of both words overlap a lot, but there is one difference I can perhaps think of. *Envisage* is commonly used as a synonym for *predict* or *anticipate*. *Envision* is less likely to be used for the same.

> I do not envisage a growth in telecommunications sector in the next two years.

*Envision*, on the other hand, could be used when you imagine something fancy or a remote possibility. To quote an example from [here](http://thefreedictionary.com/envision),

> "I can't envision him on horseback!"

The difference may be one that never exists in practice, but I do feel *envisage* is commoner in business circles than *envision*.

Comment: I'm not sure about your points on the why and the where ... But, it is interesting that Google Ngrams appears to concur with your example when you perform a simple comparison of "envision/envisage him _on_" with "envision/envisage him _as_". There are zero results for "envisage him as", with the other combinations returning multiple hits.

Comment: @coleopterist: Hmmm... I am not sure how best to use Ngrams to justify my point. Not sure if checking merely on the basis of prepositions will suffice.

Comment: Actually, my last comment should read, "There are zero results for 'envisage him _on_'" :/ I'm not sure how best to filter usage examples in Ngrams either. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

From OED, we have the earlier “envisage” as

> **Etymology**: < French envisage-r, < en- (see en- prefix1) + visage visage n., face.
>
> 1. transitive. **To look in the face of; figurative to face (danger, etc.); to look straight at.**
>
> 1820   J. Keats Hyperion: a Fragm. ii, in Lamia & Other Poems 178   *To envisage circumstance, all calm, That is the top of sovereignty.*

This quickly (16  years later) took on a broader meaning

> **2.a. To obtain a mental view of, set before the mind's eye; to contemplate; chiefly, to view or regard under a particular aspect.**
>
> 1836   J. Herschel in C. Babbage 9th Bridgewater Treat. (1837) App. I. 211   *Envisaging the case algebraically.*

This is probably a slight misunderstanding of the original "envisage" justified by the fact that one could not look something in the face without having a mental picture of the whole.

The word “**envision**” is first recorded a century later,

> **Etymology**: < en- prefix + vision n.

> *transitive*. **To see or foresee as in a vision; to envisage; to visualize.**
>
> 1921   L. Strachey Queen Victoria vii. 221   *His blackest hypochondria had never envisioned quite so miserable a Catastrophe.*

These demonstrate the transition from the original “envisage” in which one had to envisage (face) something and thus by envisaging it, one could not help but mentally see the whole thing, i.e. to envision which, I suspect, was a misunderstanding or eggcorn of envisage in its slightly later sense.

Any difference that there now is, is in the nuance that envisage is what most people do, and envision is a more formal action with less of the figurative but much the same thing.

Comment: There are many other examples of this sort of convergence of meanings in English. To underscore, their historical definitions provide a lot of context into their potentially nuanced usage, where it may make more sense to use one over the other. Interestingly, given the graphs provided by Lynn, you could speculate that the usefulness of their nuance may be influencing their usage in both American English and British English. The declining usage of `envision` seems to plateauing in British English, while usage of `envisage` in American English seems to be increasing.

Answer (score 0):

An amusing Australian site states that “envisage” is to anticipate or contemplate about something real, and “envision” is to imagine or mentally picture anything.  See https://www.writerscentre.com.au/blog/qa-envisage-vs-envision/. It also appears that “envision” is an American invention coming quite a bit later than “envisage” but apparently it is the process of replacing it elsewhere too.

Answer (score -1):

Envision could be imagining some future event occurring where envisage could be the liklihood of it happening a reality.

Answer (score -1):

I saw the best distinction between the two words I have ever seen at https://grammarist.com/usage/envision-envisage/.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/425181)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Relevant discussion should be reified rather than left for visitors / contributors to envision/envisage.